# Dynamic memory allocation being overwritten?

Tags: c++, pointers, memory, dynamic, constructor

I am having massive problems with my code. I do not understand why this is happening and having no idea how to fix it.

Basically I have tried to define an array of pointers to characters where each element of the array of pointers stores a different set of characters.

**Class constructor:**
(note: size is an integer which specifies how large my array of pointers should be, the user can define this)

```
storeElements = new char*[size];
```

Say the size = 3, now storeElements should be an array of pointers capable of pointing to 3 separate strings of characters.

```
*storeElements = "one"; 
*(storeElements+1) = "two"; 
*(storeElements+2) = "three";
```

When I print these values straight after assigning them, they print the correct strings, however later on in my code, in other functions and after many other variables have been declared, and I have opened an output text file, *storeElements kind of gets muddled up.

Say for example, if I tried to do this (later on in my code):

```
cout << *(storeElements+2) << endl;
```

**Instead of printing "three" it might print "one" or nothing at all.**

There has got to be a problem with dynamic memory allocation here because I am reading from text files and sometimes the contents of that text file gets stored in the elements of *storeElements **without me assigning them to *storeElements at all**

Please help me better understand how to fix this. I've invested a lot of time and effort into my code and am very upset over this. Thank you for taking the time out of your day to help me.

Comment: If you are on Linux, valgrind may help. Anyhow, boiling down your code to the bare minimum that reproduces the problem gives people here on SO a better chance of helping out.

Comment: One guess is that you read from the file without allocating enough space to store each line. Have you tried using `std::vector<std::string>>`?

Comment: Please distill an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) out of your code, and post that. This is unanswerable without actual code.

Comment: *storeElements  = "one" and alike assignments are storing string literals into some random memory location pointed by storeElements. You need to allocate space for storeElements[0..2] before assigning values to them.

Comment: @Arun See the OP's line `storeElements = new char*[size];` right above.

Comment: I'm reading into a text file using ifstream and storing each string (separated by white space) into a string variable, then storing that string variable into one of the elements of storeElements.

Comment: Are you guys saying that because I haven't allocated space for the size of the string that I've set storeElements to point to, it gets muddled up?

Comment: @Jared If the strings aren’t known in the compile time (like you provided in the question), you’ll need the stuff like space allocation for the strings and `strcpy()`. Or you can switch to `std::string` and it will do the dirty work for you.

Comment: My educated guess: you are building temporary buffers and storing their address in storeElements[i]. When the temporary buffer is deleted or overwritten with other stuff storeElements[i] still Points to the buffer - but to other buffer content (string).

Comment: @Melebius I tried this, where temp is a string variable which I am extracting the contents of a text file from: *(storeElements+i) = new char[strlen(temp)+1]; --- and then I'm trying to do this: ---
strcpy(*(storeElements+i),temp );

Comment: @Melebius however I'm getting "cannot convert std::string" to "" * const char" errors

Comment: should be strcpy(*(storeElements+i),temp.c_str() );

Answer (score 2):

It's simple, you have allocated memory for the pointers, however you haven't allocated memory for the char arrays that they pointers point to.

This line of code is perfect.

```
storeElements = new char*[size];
```

Now if you look at this line of code:

```
*storeElements = "one";
```

You haven't allocated any memory to store "one". What you should so is allocate memory before you assign the values. Something like:

```
*storeElements = new char[strlen("one")+1];
strcpy_s(storeElements[0], strlen("one")+1, "one");
```

Comment: C-strings don’t work this way. The line `*storeElements = "one";` sets the pointer to the location of the unnamed `const char[] = "one"` provided by compiler. Its data remain available until the program ends, so this is not the problem until you decide to modify the string. In fact, your last line loses a reference to the space allocated on the line before.

Comment: Basically, the code works at first since he points to a constant string literal. If he then wants to modify the strings, he needs to allocate space for the modified string.

Comment: @ErikAlapää Yes, but in that case he’ll need `strcpy()` and not plain assignment.

Comment: @Melebius Yes, absolutely. May be important to point that out.

Comment: How would I use strcpy_s? I've #include <string.h> and <string> but it's giving me "strcpy_s was not declared in the scope"

Comment: @Jared It’s a new feature in C++11. If not present, use original `strcpy()` from `<cstring>` (or `<string.h>`).

Comment: When I switch back to strcpy() I get an error "too many arguments to function char* strcpy" which I assume to be because in the code above strcpy_s is using 3 arguments

Comment: @Jared Yes, it works without the length argument (the middle one). http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strcpy

Comment: The compiler now is spitting some "cannot convert std::string to const char* for argument when I do those two lines (strlen and strcpy). As a novice, I tried to stop this warning using the (char*) cast but I'm really not sure if this is the correct way to do it, and thus further errors are made

Comment: Since storeElements is supposed to be an array of pointers (char *), how would I properly do this without the conversion errors? Could it be how I've defined it in the constructor?

Comment: @Jared What constructor? We haven’t seen any of your classes yet. The right way to get `const char []` from `std::string` is calling its `c_str()` method.

Comment: `"one".c_str()` is absolute nonsense. `"one"` does not have members, it's an array.

Comment: @Angew, Sorry my mistake. `string ("one").c_str()` should do.